# FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges keeps getting called

Tags: flutter

In main.dart I've added this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((event) async {
      debugPrint('user state changed in main');
    });
```

The event is continuously getting triggered, with no changes to the users logged in status (I am developing for the web, not tested on devices).

Answer (score 0):

Use `authStateChanges` when interested in the current user.

[authStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html)

> Notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state (such as sign-in or sign-out).

[userChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html)

> Notifies about changes to any user updates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was isolated - I was calling this inside the .listen((event) async {}

```
token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdTokenResult(true);
```

which was triggering the event again...

Comment: can u post the full code, having similar issue